# Why are the sections inside a UITableView in a different order on different devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I have implemented a UITableViewController inside my app. Everything is working fine except the order of the sections inside this TableView.

The number of sections and the number of rows inside each section are OK. I fetch some values from my server and display them inside my TableView. They are sorted by date, and each section contains the values that are related to that date.

Now, if I have values from yesterday (11.11.2014) and from today (12.11.2014), on my iPhone 6 the section 12.11.2014 is displayed first. On the iPhone 5, the 11.11.2014-section is displayed first - but it's the same code! I don't know how to solve that problem.

Here are 2 screenshots so you know what I mean:

**iPhone 5 screenshot**
[image: iPhone 5 screenshot]

**iPhone 6 screenshot**
[image: iPhone 6 screenshot]

On the second screenshot the 12.11.2014-is displayed first.

EDIT:
My TableView displays the latest trades of bitcoins. I have a NSMutableDictionary which has 2 entries (in my example here), one entry for "12.11.2014" and one entry for "11.11.2014", so my *numberOfSections*-method returns 2.

```
var trades : NSMutableDictionary!

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return trades.count
}
```

Now, each entry in that dictionary contains a list of trades, so the type of my dictionary is simply:

```
String : [Trade]
```

So my *numberOfRowsInSection* looks like this (I know it's a bit tricky):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (self.trades.objectForKey((self.trades.allKeys as NSArray).objectAtIndex(section) as String)! as [Trade]).count
}
```

Like I said, on iPhone 6 it's working fine, on iPhone 5 not.

Comment: The tableview is only in the order your data tells it to be in. Without seeing any code it's impossible to say anything else. If you are not making sure the data is sorted then this could happen. Actually, I'm guessing you've put your "section" data into an `NSDictionary`. Is that right?

Comment: sorry, edited my question!

Comment: Could you please tell me how to sort the data manually? It's a bit confusing that this is working differently on different devices..

Answer (score 5):

You are storing your "section" data in an `NSDictionary`.

`NSDictionary` is an unordered collection. There is no such thing as "order" in an NSDictionary. To say that the order changes has no meaning.

If you want to store things in a dictionary and get them out in the same order then you need to sort the array of keys `self.trade.allKeys` before you get things out of it.

It is not different devices that is doing this. You may find that it will change on a single device too.

A better (different) way would be to use an NSArray to store the data instead.

Like this...

```
//self.allTrades array...
[
    {
        title  : 11.11.2014,
        trades : //array of trades for 11.11.2014
    },
    {
        title  : 12.11.2014,
        trades : //array of trades for 12.11.2014
    }
]
```

Now you can access the trade information for a section by doing...

```
self.allTrades[indexPath.section]
```

and to access an item...

```
//            1.                 2.        3.
self.allTrades[indexPath.section]["trades"][indexPath.row]
// 1. get the dictionary from the array for the section
// 2. then get the trades array from that dictionary
// 3. then get the item from that array.
```

Answer (score 0):

OK now I added some lines of code and it works perfectly now. I'm sorting the keys of my dictionary (which are Strings).

```
func sortDictionaryKeys(dict : NSDictionary) -> NSMutableArray {
    var sortedKeys = (dict.allKeys as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingSelector("compare:")
    var retArray = NSMutableArray()

    for var i = sortedKeys.count-1; i > 0; i-- {
        retArray.addObject(sortedKeys[i])
    }
    return retArray
}
```

I had to "invert" the for-Loop so the dates are sorted descending, so that the newest trades are on top of the TableView.

After sorting the keys, I access my [Trade]-list via the key stored in my *sortedKeys* array. It's not the solution @Fogmeister posted, but he gave me the tip that an NSDictionary isn't sorted at all - an NSArray **is** sorted.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It **is** the solution I posted. Third paragraph.

Comment: not exactly, I didn't change anything with my existing Dictionaries and Arrays. I just added an Array which contains my sorted keys, nothing else. You said I should store all my data in an Array - see your first code block.

Comment: Third paragraph... **If you want to store things in a dictionary and get them out in the same order then you need to sort the array of keys `self.trade.allKeys` before you get things out of it.** This is exactly what you're doing. Then I posted the code for the alternative, better solution. :)

Comment: For sorting an array in Swift you can do this... `array.sort{>}` that will sort the array in descending order :)